# Is it possible to use push email on iOS Mail app with self hosted mail server?

Tags: mobile-mail

I use a self-hosted IMAP email server. In Mail.app on OS X, the app gets any new mail pushed using `IDLE`. On my iPhone however, the Mail app only polls every so many minutes.

Under Settings > Mail > Accounts > New email the option 'Push' is not available.

Is this not supported in the iOS app, possibly because of impact on battery life? It seems strange that the Mail.app on OS X can do it while the phone can't.